# Redirect to a certain view in AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, authorize-attribute

In my `AdministratorController` I have an action with custom attribute:

```
[AuthorizedOnly (Roles = "admin, superadmin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{...}
```

The attribute is:

```
class AuthorizedOnlyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizedOnlyAttribute()
    {
        View = "~/Views/Main/Index.cshtml";
        Master = String.Empty;
    }
    public String View { get; set; }
    public String Master { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        CheckIfUserIsAuthenticated(filterContext);
    }
    private void CheckIfUserIsAuthenticated(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.Result == null)
            return;
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(View))
                return;
            var result = new ViewResult{ViewName = View, MasterName = Master};

            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
    }
```

It correctly shows me the view that I need: `~/Views/Main/Index.cshtml`
But in my browser URL is still from Administrator controller: `.../Administrator/Index`
How can I redirect to the View that I need, so that URL would also change?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
string retUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
filterContext.Result =
                 new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary 
                         {{ "controller", "Main" },
                          { "action", "Home" },
                          { "returnUrl",    retUrl } });
```

Comment: I have added System.Web.Routing to my project but Routing is not being found within the custom authorization class that i have made are any other references required?